# Eclipse 's "Run as" does not auto add "Run on Server" even to I added the Tomcat server to the Project?

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

I am coding java with eclipse and here is my problem.

I added Tomcat v10.0 to my Project successfully and as you can see in this picture

[image: Added Tomcat]

But my problem is, I do not see the "Run on Server" when I clicked to the "Run As" ? As you can see in this picture ?

[image: my problem]

I think that when I added the Tomcat successfully, the Tomcat must appeared at "Run As" ?

Could you please give me some advice ? Thank you in advance.

Comment: The problem view shows errors you have to fix first. In your `pom.xml` the Java version is missing, so the Maven default Java 5 is used, but Tomcat 10 requires Java 8 or higher. Does in your `pom.xml` adding `<properties><maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source><maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target></properties>` fix it?

Comment: What's in its `.project` file?